# ssh will not connect. Help troubleshoot

Tags: server, ssh

All servers running Ubuntu server 20.04.1. I have 4 servers.   Server A can connect well to B and C but gets connection refused from D.  B and C can connect easily to D.  D can ssh into A, B, And C. Filezilla(sftp) works fine from A to D.

All ssh commands are the same.  ssh.config and sshd.config seems all the same.

A:~$ ssh D@D will fail.
A:~$ ssh B@B works flawlessley  C@C as well.

B:~$ ssh D@D works fine. from C:~$ as well.

D:~$ ssh ANY@ANY works fine.

I need A to D to connect and that is the only combination that fails:)

Comment: Are these servers on the same network? If they’re on Amazon, are they all using the same security group policies? 

Comment: A and B are in USA different states. Self hosted. Bare metal installs. C is in Thailand. and D in Laos. All same installs. 18.04 ubuntu server with KDE on top.  Then all upgraded to 20.04.1

Comment: Curious problem. Another point to consider while debugging is to turn off any host VPNs. I've had SSH timeout problems. Are you using nmap or telnet to see if the port (probably 22) is correct?

Comment: What exactly means "fails" ? No connection? Permission denied?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the insightful comments.  The issue is gone now. All my servers can talk to each other again.

It appears that the ISP was blocking my connection at some level thinking I was a bot. AND there was some strange mismatched key on machine D that maybe would not accept the ssh handshake.

Followup: No VPNs were running. Fails "no route to host"  Route was done directly to static IP, through Zerotier and through DNS.  All failed at the time.

Thanks again to the community,

Walt